# MySQL - Geo - Get nearest parish given co-ordinates

Tags: mysql, sql

The following is the SQL I use for locating parishes within a given distance from given lat/lng co-ordinates:

```
SELECT record_id as parish_id, parish, church, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(#sLat#) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(#sLng#) ) + sin( radians(#sLat#) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM parishes
HAVING distance < #arguments.dist# 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

How would I alter this query to get only the very CLOSEST parish to the given co-ordinates?

Comment: Can't you change it to `LIMIT 1`

Comment: Oh yeah, doh. Make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently limiting to 20 with the following statement:

`LIMIT 0,20`

You can limit to one by changing this to:

`LIMIT 1`

It will be the closest because you are ordering by `distance`.